# Optimising a nasty function in python - errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to minimise a function of three variables, nonlinear, and very big and nasty. It works in Matlab just fine, but I'm trying to transfer over to python (as a learning experience and more freedom). Anyway, it does work for with the minimize function 'Nelder-Mead', but it is giving me an output that doesn't make sense, so I'm trying to add bounds to my variables.

Here's the code:

```
bnds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
x0 = [0.004, 0.1, 0.1]
res = minimize(myObjFun, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds)
print(res)
```

The output from Matlab gives me the three values which minimize the function: [0.2182, 0.0684, 0.0048], while the Nelder-Mead in python gave something completely different and way out of the bounds I want (should be between 0 and 1).

Here's the error:

```
File "****/fixedpoints.py", line 45, in <module>
    res = minimize(myObjFun, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 380, in minimize
callback=callback, **options)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 304, in _minimize_lbfgsb
isave, dsave)
TypeError: _lbfgsb.setulb() 6th argument (f) can't be converted to double
```

Comment: Without seeing the function `myObjFun`, it would be very difficult to say why `scipy` is struggling to find its minimum. Could you show the function?

Answer (score 2):

We can't debug unless you give us `myObjFun` or a similar function (based on simpler or faked data) that has similar behavior during optimization.  More specifically your code will work on a well behaved myObjFun; e.g.,

```
>>> import scipy.optimize
>>> def myObjFun(x):
        return (x[0]-.2182)**4 + (x[1]-.0684)**2 + 5*(x[2]-.0048)**2 + 3.2
>>> print scipy.optimize.minimize(myObjFun, [0.004,0.1,0.1], method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=((0,1),(0,1),(0,1)))
  status: 0
 success: True
    nfev: 18
     fun: 3.200000001787815
       x: array([ 0.21213686,  0.06837957,  0.00480194])
 message: 'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
     jac: array([ -8.88178420e-07,  -4.08562073e-05,   1.94511074e-05])
     nit: 17
```

Now parameter f of setulb contains the current value of the objective function as the function is being evaluated [[1]](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/appl/lbfgsb.c):

```
   f is a double precision variable.
 On first entry f is unspecified.
 On final exit f is the value of the function at x.
```

So the value of your objective function computed at some point over the search space seems to inadvertently be unconvertible to float for some reason (that seems to be a TypeError).

I can get a similar error (but actually an `OverflowError`) with say this objective function, which is normally well behaved but blows up whenever `x[1] < 0.0685` (which should happen before the minimum is found):

```
>>> def myObjFun(x):                                                                                       
        return (x[0]-.2182)**4 + (x[1]-.0684)**2 + 5*(x[2]-.0048)**2 + 3.2 if x[1] > 0.0684 else 10**999
   ....: 

>>> print scipy.optimize.minimize(myObjFun, [0.004,0.1,0.1], method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=((0,1),(0,1),(0,1)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-9204b704b51a> in <module>()
----> 1 print scipy.optimize.minimize(myObjFun, [0.004,0.1,0.1], method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=((0,1),(0,1),(0,1)))

lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.pyc in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    376     elif meth == 'l-bfgs-b':
    377         return _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 378                                 callback=callback, **options)
    379     elif meth == 'tnc':
    380         return _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, callback=callback,

lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.pyc in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, **unknown_options)
    302         _lbfgsb.setulb(m, x, low_bnd, upper_bnd, nbd, f, g, factr,
    303                        pgtol, wa, iwa, task, iprint, csave, lsave,
--> 304                        isave, dsave)
    305         task_str = task.tostring()
    306         if task_str.startswith(b'FG'):

OverflowError: _lbfgsb.setulb() 6th argument (f) can't be converted to double
```

So I'd carefully check your myObjFun and manually evaluate it at many points in the searched domain and see that the returned values are reasonable and of the correct types and match what matlab returns.